# Is it possible to keep python file running in the background and keep refreshing render_template?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask, anychart

So I am using flask to create a dictionary in python which is then passed into my html template through render_template to create an AnyChart Gantt Resource Chart. Currently, my .py file is able to take in user input in the python shell to build the dictionary list which is then passed through and the chart is visualized accurately.
However, my current implementation requires the entire dictionary to be completed before being rendered, which makes sense because the return call exits the function.

I was wondering if there was a method to extend my program and allow for the chart to be rendered multiple times as the list is continuously updated. For example, after each row is added into the dictionary, it would be cool if the chart could be rendered and displayed. New to flask and js, so apologies for any confusion.

run.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

 
@app.route("/")
def main():
    dataList = [] # list of dictionaries that is passed as data

    # while loop code that prompts for user input and then added to dataList

    pros = json.dumps(dataList)
    return render_template('template.html'), data = prs)
```

template.html

```
var data = {{data | safe}};
var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-tree");
var chart = anychart.ganttResource();
chart.data(treeData);

// bunch of formatting code

chart.draw();
```

Comment: You could reload the page periodically using Javascript.

Comment: That's true, but the way my .py file is set up, I believe it would reset the dataList to be empty. :(